# Horizontally scrolling div within display:table div?

Tags: html, css

I am able to make a horizontally scrolling div using the following:

#### CSS

```
.scroll {
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    overflow-x:auto;
    white-space:nowrap;
}

.box {
    width:200px;
    height:100%;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

#### HTML

```
<div class="scroll">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

However, once this is nested inside a div with `display:table`, the `.scroll` div no longer scrolls and instead stretches the `.scroll` div to show all of the boxes.

Pretty sure there's an easy fix for this, any ideas?

For reference: http://jsbin.com/makigome/29/edit?html,css,output

Comment: Why do you want it to be `display: table`?

Comment: `display:table` will apply the table style of property to it so yes it will stretch but why you want to use `display:table`?

Comment: The page has a three-column layout with each of them being `display:table-cell`. I'm trying to get a scrolling div within one of them, taking up 100% of the width of the column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested, I fixed this by setting `position:absolute` to the `.scroll` div and wrapping it within another div with `position:relative` like so:

http://jsbin.com/makigome/39/edit?html,css,output

```
<div class="table">
    <div class="table-cell">
        <div class="scroll-wrapper">
            <div class="scroll">
                <div class="box"></div>
                <div class="box"></div>
                <div class="box"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

.table {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
}

.table-cell {
    display:table-cell;
    width:100%;
}

.scroll-wrapper {
    height:100px;
    position:relative;
}

.scroll {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    overflow-x:auto;
    white-space:nowrap;
    position:absolute;
}

.box {
    width:200px;
    height:100%;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS, hope it helps

```
.table {
  display: block;
  width:100%;
}

.table-cell {
  display:block;
  width:100%;
}

.scroll {
  height:100px;
  width:100%;
  overflow-x:auto;
  border:1px solid red;
  white-space:nowrap;
  margin:10px 0px;
}

.box {
  width:200px;
  height:100%;
  background:orange;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

Comment: :) That would work but the `.table` and `.table-cell` classes need to maintain `display:table` and `display:table-cell` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Is not possible using table and table cell, you can do it using float like this:

```
.table {
  float:left;
  width:100%;
}

.table-cell {
  float:left;
  width:100%;
}

.scroll {
  clear:both;
  height:100px;
  width:100%;
  overflow-x:auto;
  border:1px solid red;
  white-space:nowrap;
  margin:10px 0px;
}

.box {
  width:200px;
  height:100%;
  background:orange;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
}
```